# SQL assign numbers to dates, grouped by a value

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join

Using SQL, how could I give values to dates, grouped by each company?

Current Table:

```
Date            Company          Employees

2012-04-28      Apple, Inc.      7543
2012-04-27      Apple, Inc.      7510
2012-04-26      Apple, Inc.      7484

2012-04-28      Google, Inc.     11303
2012-04-27      Google, Inc.     11300
2012-04-26      Google, Inc.     11280
2012-04-25      Google, Inc.     11278
2012-04-24      Google, Inc.     11254
```

Desired Table:

```
Date            company_day      Company          Employees

2012-04-28      3                Apple, Inc.      7543
2012-04-27      2                Apple, Inc.      7510
2012-04-26      1                Apple, Inc.      7484

2012-04-28      5                Google, Inc.     11303
2012-04-27      4                Google, Inc.     11300
2012-04-26      3                Google, Inc.     11280
2012-04-25      2                Google, Inc.     11278
2012-04-24      1                Google, Inc.     11254
```

The value for company_day begins at the earliest date for each company. company_day is company specific.

Comment: what is the logic to determine the company day?

Comment: @bluefeet it looks like the earliest day in the table is 1, then enumerated from there.

Comment: @MatthewPK that is my guess too but they need to clarify the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first get the `MIN` date for each company.

Then you can `JOIN` the result of that query and simply display the difference between it and the Date column.

```
SELECT 
    MyTable.[Date]
    ,DATEDIFF(MyTable.[Date], MinTable.[MinDate]) + 1 AS Company_Day
    ,MyTable.[Company]
    ,MyTable.[Employees]
FROM
    MyTable
JOIN
    (
    SELECT 
        MIN(b.[Date]) AS MinDate
        , b.[Company] 
    FROM 
       MyTable b 
    GROUP BY 
        b.[Company]
    ) AS MinTable
        ON MinTable.[Company] = MyTable.[Company]
```

Something like that. This code is untested, but should be close.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp

Comment: Thanks Matt - what would be effective code for this? I have about 5,000 companies in the table so finding MIN dates by hand will tough.

Comment: Ha - you posted code before I could post the comment. Thanks, let me check it out!

Comment: @MatthewPK FYI - there are much better resources to reference than w3schools.com

Comment: @bluefeet, I googled `MySQL DATEDIFF` and linked the first result. If OP wants to get more in depth information he will easily be able to do so with what I've provided so far. I edited in a more official link to satisfy any deficiencies.

Comment: @bluefeet please provide useful information instead of criticizing people answering my questions.

Comment: @DonnyP I am not criticizing the answer, I was offering up a suggestion to not use w3schools as a reference.  This is a common school of thought on SO, do not use w3schools.